# Show that the difference between two quadratic equations is > 0

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms

Given the following two equations, I want to show that equation (2) - equation (1) $\geq$ 0 under some conditions.

Eqn (1)

$$(Ab - ADEb)^T(Ab - ADEb)$$

Eqn (2)

$$(Ab - AD^*Eb)^T(Ab - AD^*Eb)$$

where all of the vectors/matrices are real:

- $A$ is $m \times n$
- $b$ is $n \times 1$
- $D$ and $D^*$ are both $n \times p$, but $D \neq D^*$ (note that $D^*$ is not the conjugate transpose of $D$).
- $E$ is $p \times n$

The first thing I tried was to expand both Eqn(1) and (2).

Eqn (1)

\begin{align*}
(Ab - ADEb)^T(Ab - ADEb) &= b^TA^TAb - 2b^TE^TD^TA^TAb + b^TE^TD^TA^TADEb
\end{align*}

Eqn (2)

\begin{align*}
(Ab - AD^*Eb)^T(Ab - AD^*Eb) &= b^TA^TAb - 2b^TE^T{D^*}^TA^TAb + b^TE^T{D^*}^TA^TAD^*Eb
\end{align*}

Then I take the difference: Eqn (2) - Eqn (1)

\begin{align*}
Eqn (2) - Eqn (1)  &= -2b^TE^T{D^*}^TA^TAb + b^TE^T{D^*}^TA^TAD^*Eb + 2b^TE^TD^TA^TAb - b^TE^TD^TA^TADEb\\
&= -2b^TE^T({D^*}^TA^T - D^TA^T)Ab + b^TE^T({D^*}^TA^TAD^* - D^TA^TAD)Eb\\ 
&\overset{?}{\geq} 0
\end{align*}

This brings me to

\begin{align*}2b^TE^T({D^*}^TA^T - D^TA^T)Ab &\overset{?}{\leq} b^TE^T({D^*}^TA^TAD^* - D^TA^TAD)Eb
\end{align*}

It's clear that the LHS = RHS if $D^* = D$. My question is, how can I go about coming up with conditions for which the strict inequality, $$2b^TE^T({D^*}^TA^T - D^TA^T)Ab < b^TE^T({D^*}^TA^TAD^* - D^TA^TAD)Eb$$ would hold?

Comment: Just to confirm, $D^* = $ the conjugate transpose of $D$? And do you know anything about if these matrices are real or anything?

Comment: @cmitch Sorry for the confusion. $D^*$ is not the conjugate transpose of $D$ (I was trying to indicate that $D^*$ is a different matrix from $D$ via the asterisk). All matrices are real. I will edit my original post.

Comment: What conditions do you have? Since without conditions you could just switch $D$ and $D^*$, which would mean that those two equations must always equal each other, which would not be true if you set $D = 0$

Comment: Switching the independent variable from $D\to X$, what you really have here is the scalar function $\,f(X)=\|A(I-XE)b\|_F^2.\;$ The question is how this function behaves as $X$ changes. I would suggest calculating its gradient wrt $X$.

Comment: @cmitch What conditions do you think would be helpful? Conditions on $D^*$, $D$? Or conditions on the other vectors/matrices in the expression?

Comment: Any conditions, but I would look at @greg's comment, namely the part that it looks like a norm. The algebraic manipulation makes me think of positive definite ($x^T A x > 0$ when $x \ne 0$) matrices and positive semidefinite (same but >=). These are also directly related to the eigenvalues of matrices (all positive for definite and all positive or 0 for semidefinite).

Comment: Note that these conditions are guaranteed for symmetric matrices, so $D^T A^T A D$ is symmetric, so all eigenvalues are nonnegative, so $b^T E^T D^T A^T A D E b >= 0$. From this, I would also consider looking into eigenvalue comparisons: $x^TAx >= |x|^2 min(\lambda_A)$ when A is positive semi definite, so you could argue that the right side of your last equation being positive if $\lambda_{min} (E^TD^{*T} A^TAD^*E)> \lambda_{max}(E^TD^TA^TADE)$, which since $Eb$ is a vector, could also be $\lambda_{min} (D^{*T} A^TAD)> \lambda_{max}(D^TA^TAD)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the matrix variable as $X\,$
and define the vector function
$$v(X) = AXEb-Ab$$
[Vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the $X$ matrix on the RHS yields
$$\eqalign{
v &= {\rm vec}(AXEb) - Ab \\
  &= (b^TE^T\otimes A)\,{\rm vec}(X) - Ab \\
  &= Mx-Ab \\
}$$
Write down the squared magnitude of this vector,
and calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\mu &= v^Tv \\
d\mu &= 2v^Tdv = 2v^TM\,dx = 2(M^Tv)^Tdx \\
\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x} &= 2M^Tv \;=\; g
 \qquad\big({\rm the\,gradient}\big) \\
}$$
You are interested in $\mu$ at two different values of $x$ such that
$$\eqalign{
\mu(x^*) &> \mu(x) \\
\Delta \mu \equiv \mu(x^*) - \mu(x) &> 0 \\
}$$
The difference $(x^*-x)$ can be parameterized
by a direction $(s)$ and a length $(\lambda>0)$
$$\eqalign{
s = \frac{x^*-x}{\|x^*-x\|}
,\qquad \|s\| = 1 
,\qquad (x^*-x)=\lambda s 
}$$
The gradient can be used with this parameterization to calculate
$$\eqalign{
\Delta\mu = g^T(\lambda s) = \lambda(g^Ts)\; > 0  \\
\therefore\;\; g^Ts \; > 0  \\
}$$
In words, the projection of the unit vector $s$ onto the gradient $g$ must be positive. This is closely related to the concept of
the *directional derivative*.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into this. Could you explain to me what it means in layman's terms that the "projection of $s$ onto $g$ must be positive"? Since $s$ is a direction, what does it mean to project a "direction $s$" onto the gradient? And what does it mean for such a projection to be positive?